# Does alcohol make you warmer?

Tags: physiology, alcohol

A lot of people seem to think that they can walk around in t-shirts in midwinter after having a few drinks, and people often feel warmer after drinking alcoholic drinks. However, are they actually getting warmer?

If they drunk a warm drink, then they would get warmer. But many drinks are served "ice-cold" and the effect is still claimed.

Is the alcohol actually causing the body to warm up, or does it just make people feel warmer?

Comment: @DanGetz Yes, it's probably a duplicate, even though it's coming from the other angle. Thanks for the VTC.